# CakePHP 1.3 (newest), fatal error while baking views

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-bake

I've just downloaded the newest beta of CakePHP 1.3 for a new project
(not a serious one, so no worries with the beta, still learning stuff,
I'm right now trying to get grip on acl/auth).

I've baked model and controllers for four databases, but baking a view
results in a fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function on a non-object in /
my_project_folder/cake/console/libs/tasks/controller.php on line 400
```

I realize that it's just a beta, but maybe someone has already found a
quick way to fix it?

Regards,
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [ticket](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/186-php-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-on-a-non-object-in-cakephpcakeconsolelibstaskscontrollerphp-on-line-400) for this issue.